# I want to use .flatMap() but it is not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am creating a note app so first I created a file Failures
its contents:

```
@freezed  
abstract class ValueFailure<Type> with _$ValueFailure<Type> {
  const factory ValueFailure.invalidEmail({
    required Type failedValue
  }) = InvalidEmail<Type>;
  const factory ValueFailure.shortPassword({
    required Type failedValue
  }) = ShortPassword<Type>;
   const factory ValueFailure.exceedinglength({
    required Type failedValue,
    required int max
  }) = ExceedingLength<Type>;
   const factory ValueFailure.listTooLong({
    required Type failedValue,
    required int max
  }) = ListTooLong<Type>;
   const factory ValueFailure.empty({
    required Type failedValue
  }) = Empty<Type>;
   const factory ValueFailure.multiLine({
    required Type failedValue
  }) = MultiLine<Type>;
}
```

then created ValidatedValueObject File
its contents:

```
Either<ValueFailure<String>, String> validateMaxStringLength(
    String input, int maxLength) {
  if (input.length <= maxLength) {
    return Right(input);
  } else {
    return Left(
        ValueFailure.exceedinglength(failedValue: input, max: maxLength));
  }
}

Either<ValueFailure<String>, String> validateStringNotEmpty(String input) {
  if (input.isNotEmpty) {
    return Right(input);
  } else {
    return Left(ValueFailure.empty(failedValue: input));
  }
}

Either<ValueFailure<String>, String> validateSingleLine(String input) {
  if (input.contains('\n')) {
    return Left(ValueFailure.multiLine(failedValue: input));
  } else {
    return Right(input);
  }
}
Either<ValueFailure<KtList<Type>>, KtList<Type>> validateMaxListLength<Type>(
    KtList<Type> input, int maxLength){
         if (input.size <= maxLength) {
    return Right(input);
  } else {
    return Left(
        ValueFailure.listTooLong(failedValue: input, max: maxLength));
  } 
    }
```

And then I created ValueObject File. This is where I am facing problem.
Its contents:

```
class MovieObject extends ValueObject<String> {
  @override
  final Either<ValueFailure<String>, String> value;
  static const maxLength = 20;
  factory MovieObject(String input) {
    return MovieObject._(validateMaxStringLength(input,maxLength).flatMap(validateStringNotEmpty(input)));
  }

  const MovieObject._(this.value);
}
```

error getting:

> The method 'flatMap' isn't defined for the type 'Either'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'flatMap'.

Actually I am not able to find a solution

Comment: Where are you getting `Either` from? Did you define it yourself? Is it defined in a 3rd party library, and if so which library? Does it have a `.flatMap` method defined on it? Because the compiler is telling you it does not.

Comment: Either is coming from dartz library

Comment: Well it looks like the `Either` class in dartz does have a `.flatMap` method (https://pub.dev/documentation/dartz/latest/dartz/Either/flatMap.html). Are you on the latest version of the dartz library? There is a chance it might not be there in an older version of the library.

Comment: Yes I'm using the latest version

Comment: `dartz` is listed at version `0.10.1` in both `pubspec.yaml` and `pubspec.lock`? When you mouse over `Either` in your ide, the tooltip says its from `package:dartz/dartz.dart`?

Comment: In general, stop using dartz.  fpdart is actively maintained, far better documented, better tested, and generally a better choice.